# Measure noise in android

Tags: android, audio, audio-recording

I am able to detect voice with the help of voice recognition in android but want to measure the intensity of voice and after measuring intensity perform another task accordingly.
I am doing as follows:

```
   @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.voicerecogscreen);

    speakButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.speakButton);

    wordsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    List<ResolveInfo> activities = pm.queryIntentActivities(
            new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH), 0);
    if (activities.size() == 0)
    {
        speakButton.setEnabled(false);
        speakButton.setText("Recognizer not present");
    }        
}

/**
 * Handle the action of the button being clicked
 */
public void speakButtonClicked(View v)
{
    startVoiceRecognitionActivity();
}

/**
 * Fire an intent to start the voice recognition activity.
 */
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);        
}

/**
 * Handle the results from the voice recognition activity.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {

        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        wordsList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                matches));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually to measure audio power (intensity) you would get PCM data using [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html)
but I doubt it that you can do that while using `Speech Recognizer` "not sure". but this methold if worked should give you quality results.

if it didn't work:

In [SpeechRecognizer Listener API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html) there is : [onRMSChanged](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html#onRmsChanged%28float%29) and [onBufferReceived](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/RecognitionListener.html#onBufferReceived%28byte%5B%5D%29)

where:

- **onRMSChanged** gives you the current RMS value of audio signal (how strong is the signal)
- **onBufferReceived** and `AudioRecorder` should use the same technique to find RMS Value from PCM sample. take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800649/how-to-detect-silence-when-recording-in-java/5800854#5800854)

Note: not all `SpeechRecognizerListener` APIs gets called on all devices so you need to be careful and use test driven approach for this problem.