# How can I get volume level (or dB) of microphone input with alsa API?

Tags: ubuntu, microphone, alsa

I can do it with command line : arecord -vv , but I need to finish it with code , I don't known which API can make it .

Answer (score 0):

`arecord` just looks at the captured samples (it uses the maximum in a certain interval).

You can do the same yourself. You also need to know what level a full-scale sample corresponds to.

Also see [Detect silence when recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800649/detect-silence-when-recording).

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping !!! actually I can capture the audio stream but can't parse the level of volume from it . Or is there any API can get volume dB directly ?