# How to detect Silence in Speech to Text?

Tags: android, speech-to-text, dialogflow-es

I'm developing an Android Voice Assistant (Using `Dialogflow`), and I'm able to control when the user start the request.

```
@Override
public void onListeningStarted() {
    ImageView fab_img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fab_img);
    fab_img.startAnimation(performAnimation);
}
```

And that start an animation for the mic icon.
After that, when they finish the question or speech, I can use this to stop the animation.

```
@Override
public void onListeningFinished() {
    ImageView fab_img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.fab_img);
    fab_img.clearAnimation();
}
```

But if the user does not speak, and the mic just close after a period of time, I'm not able to detect that.
I have tried with this:

```
@Override
public void onListeningCanceled() {

}
```

But it's not working, and with the result of the query, but no luck.
Any ideas?
Thanks.

EDIT------
The suggested solution of @sunil sunny looks fine

```
@Override
public void onAudioLevel(float level) {

}
```

Right now I'm working on the amount of time that the silence level needs to be produced.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect silence when recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5800649/detect-silence-when-recording)

Comment: Add a fallback intent in Dialogflow which will reprompt the question to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used this API but from the documentation, I saw a method called `void onAudioLevel(float level); // callback for sound level visualization` which can be used for silence detection I guess. It's returning a float value so first, find out what is the normal value when a user speaks and also find out the value range when the user is in silence. Let's assume A is the value when a user speaks and B is the value when user not speaking. Then if you are getting B for say 5 secs then the user is in silence.

Comment: One can keep an array of sound levels of last 3 seconds, at every instance check whether the median sound level in the array is below a certain threshold. This way one can better determine silence during speaking.

Comment: @Waterbyte I have just given a rough idea. Implementation he has to do it himself and I agree with your point.

Comment: I may need a little more help. the `@Override public void onAudioLevel(float level { }` was good, but hard to catch an average of the sound and any variable created inside, will only exist while a sound is being captured. So the best way to go is `onListeningFinished ` the bad part is that is only called in random times.

Comment: @pasandor Since I haven't tried the API I am quite not sure how 'onAudioLevel' works. However, I will try the API and update my answer with code if I am getting some free time.